# dl dt dd tags - can we add any tags between dd?

Tags: css, html, standards

My menu is designed with `dl dt dd` tags. 'One', 'two',... are menu items. 'Header' is menu header.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Header</dt>
    <dd>One</dd>
    <dd>Two</dd>
    <dd>Three</dd>
    <dd>Four</dd>
    <dd>Five</dd>
</dl>
```

My problem is if the `Header` tag is clicked, the 'One', 'two',.. options should be hidden. For that I added those `dd` options in div. I know adding div is not allowed in dl. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

```
<dl>
    <dt>Header</dt>
    <div id="menuOptions">
    <dd>One</dd>
    <dd>Two</dd>        
    <dd>Three</dd>
    <dd>Four</dd>
    <dd>Five</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: Not really clear: how an extra div should solve the problem? And why are you using that markup? it doesn't seem at all a description list

Comment: use Toggle() in Jquery/Javascript on your div. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @nicael - correct response is to edit it like wot I did :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following as a HTML structure:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Header</dt>
    <dd>
       <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>        
          <li>Three</li>
          <li>Four</li>
          <li>Five</li>
       </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

You should only have 1 definition (`dd`) for your term (`dt`).

Comment: No. Each `dt` can be followed by multiple `dd`s. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), in particular the examples which demonstrate it.

Comment: Yeah. You approach is perfect. Also passed w3c validation. Thanks Curt.

Answer (score 1):

`<dl>` Tag is one of three elements `<dl>`, `<dt>`, `<dd>`, intended to create a list of definitions. ie they are not suitable for creating menus
try like this

```
<ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Incorrect - they **are** suitable for creating menus with, however developers more usually use nested unordered lists. Perhaps you meant to say "just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should..." :-)

Comment: Using a `dl` as a menu is probably unsemantic except in specific circumstances. so the commment **"they are not suitable for creating menus"** is probbaly correct.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to identify the clicked upon definition term, and then loop over its siblings until you reach something that is not a definition description.

For example:

```
document.querySelector('dl').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    var n,
    style;

    if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'dt') {
        n = t.nextElementSibling;
        style = n.style.display === "none" ? "block": "none";
        while (n) {
          console.log(n);
            if (n.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'dd') {
                n.style.display = style;
            } else {
                break;
            }
            n = n.nextElementSibling;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that your markup is less then idea. If you want a list of menu items with another list of submenu items associated with them, then use nested lists (the child list should be in the list item element).